# _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName) just return false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am assign a role for the user, but when I check

```
_userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName)
```

It just return false and I cannot remove that role

Here is the code at userService

```
public async Task<ApiResult<bool>> RoleAssign(Guid id, RoleAssignRequest request)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
    if (user == null)
    {
        return new ApiErrorResult<bool>("Tài khoản không tồn tại");
    }
    var removedRoles = request.Roles.Where(x => x.Selected == false).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    foreach (var roleName in removedRoles)
    {
        if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName) == true)
        {
            await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, roleName);
        }
    }
    await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, removedRoles);

    var addedRoles = request.Roles.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    foreach (var roleName in addedRoles)
    {
        if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName) == false)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);
        }
    }

    return new ApiSuccessResult<bool>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, I downgraded from Dotnet core 5.0 to Dotnet core 3.1 and changed all identity framework to 3.1.1. I think it a bug.

Answer (score 0):

`RemoveFromRoleAsync` returns an `IdentityResult`, your failure is most likely listed in there

```
IdentityResult result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, roleName);
if (!result.Succeeded)
{
    // check what's in errors
    var errors = result.Errors;
}
```

Comment: i get error "UserNotInRole" when i check it,  specific description is "User is not in role 'teacher'."

Comment: var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user); when i check like this variable roles still get list role of user, what happed ? @Eric

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen when you insert manually insert the role Name into the [AspNetRoles] table, without also defining the NormalizedName. Make sure they are both defined in the role record, as the IsInRoleAsync method is actually designed against the NormalizedName field, not the Name.